# While loop problems in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am having trouble with my while loop. After it executes the third time, it won't take user input it just outputs "Enter your first name". I have tried multiple things but they don't seem to be working. The loop should continue to run until the user types in "No".

I know I'm close!

```
System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
String userInput = input.nextLine();
if (userInput.equals("Yes")) 
{
    while (userInput.equals("Yes")) 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        String lastName2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
        String address2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your city: ");
        String city2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your state: ");
        String state2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your zip code + 4: ");
        String zip2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter amount owed: ");
        String amount2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your payment amount: ");
        String payment2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the date of payment: ");
        String date2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + "XYZ Hospital");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name Information" + "\t\t\t\t" + "Address" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Payment");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Last" + "\t" + "First" + "\t\t\t" + "Address Line 1" + "\t" + "City" + "\t" + "State" + "\t" + "Zip" + "\t" + "Amount Owed" + "\t" + "Payment Amount" + "\t" + "Payment Date");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(lastName2 + " " + firstName2 + "\t" + address2 + " " + city2 + ", " + state2 + " " + zip2 + "\t" + amount2 + "\t\t" + payment2 + "\t\t" + date2);
        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
    }
}
else if (userInput.equals("No")) 
{
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
}
```

Comment: Ask for user input at the end of the loop again or put it in a do while loop

Comment: Your loop makes no sense, `userInput` is never modified inside the loop.

Comment: right up top fourth line

Comment: @mike In line 4 you are only checking the already entered userInput, not asking for new userInput. That actually happens in line 2 outside of your loop.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the do while loop? And i did ask for user input at the end of the loop

Comment: Awful, ugly code.  Unreadable.  No wonder you're having problems.  You need another userInput set in the inner loop.

Comment: No you did not ask for user input at the end. Look at your code and how often you do `userInput = input.nextLine();`. Just once and that is outside of your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never get out of your loop because `userInput` only is set once before the loop and is never set inside it, meaning you never change the `while` condition.

```
System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
String userInput = input.nextLine();
if (userInput.equals("Yes")) {
    while (userInput.equals("Yes")) {
        //your data entry...

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
        // change userInput here, else, you're never going out of the loop.
        // so add this
        userInput = input.nextLine();
    }
} else if (userInput.equals("No")) {
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
}
```

Although, your solution will probably fit your needs more in this format :

```
System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
String userInput = input.nextLine();
while (userInput.equals("Yes")) {
    //your data entry...

    System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
    userInput = input.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Goodbye");
```

This way, **while** the user enters "Yes", you will get in the loop and get out when he enters something else. If the user enters something else than "yes" from the start, you never get in the loop and close the app right away.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: @mike You're welcome. depending on your needs, you may also want to do a `do-while` loop instead. It would allow you to enter the loop at least once and ask the user if he wants to continue at only one place in your code.

Answer (score 1):

For these type of programs you can use do-while loops. That runs first time without condition and then you can get input from user in userInput variable.

```
String userInput;
 do{
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    String firstName2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    String lastName2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
    String address2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your city: ");
    String city2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your state: ");
    String state2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your zip code + 4: ");
    String zip2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter amount owed: ");
    String amount2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your payment amount: ");
    String payment2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the date of payment: ");
    String date2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + "XYZ Hospital");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Name Information" + "\t\t\t\t" + "Address" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Payment");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Last" + "\t" + "First" + "\t\t\t" + "Address Line 1" + "\t" + "City" + "\t" + "State" + "\t" + "Zip" + "\t" + "Amount Owed" + "\t" + "Payment Amount" + "\t" + "Payment Date");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(lastName2 + " " + firstName2 + "\t" + address2 + " " + city2 + ", " + state2 + " " + zip2 + "\t" + amount2 + "\t\t" + payment2 + "\t\t" + date2);
    System.out.print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: ");
    userInput = input.nextLine();

}while (userInput.equals("Yes"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are doing the while loop inside the if statement. Try to insert the if inside the loop , like this:

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter details");
    String answer=input.next();
    while(answer.equals("yes")) {
        if(answer.equals("yes")) {
System.out.println("name");
String name=input.next();
System.out.println("last name");
String last=input.next();
System.out.println("enter details");
     answer=input.next();    
} }

System.out.println("bye");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code :** Kindly check the Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class temp {
    static String userInput;
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out
                .print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No:  ");
        userInput = input.nextLine();

        while (userInput.equals("Yes")) { //while loop will iterate till "userInput is equals to Yes"
            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
            String firstName2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
            String lastName2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your address: ");
            String address2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your city: ");
            String city2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your state: ");
            String state2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your zip code + 4: ");
            String zip2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter amount owed: ");
            String amount2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your payment amount: ");
            String payment2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the date of payment: ");
            String date2 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + "XYZ Hospital");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Name Information" + "\t\t\t\t" + "Address"
                    + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Payment");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Last" + "\t" + "First" + "\t\t\t"
                    + "Address Line 1" + "\t" + "City" + "\t" + "State" + "\t"
                    + "Zip" + "\t" + "Amount Owed" + "\t" + "Payment Amount"
                    + "\t" + "Payment Date");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(lastName2 + " " + firstName2 + "\t" + address2
                    + " " + city2 + ", " + state2 + " " + zip2 + "\t" + amount2
                    + "\t\t" + payment2 + "\t\t" + date2);
            System.out
                    .print("Would you like to enter another patient? Type Yes or No: \n");
            userInput = input.nextLine(); // Taking user choice for "Yes" or "No"

            if (userInput.equals("No")) {
                break; // will Exit loop when user enter "No"
            }
        }

        if (userInput.equals("No")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Invalid input :("); // will print when user enter anything other than "Yes" or "No"

        }
    }
}
```

> You were not taking the input from the user again once you finished
>   taking data from the user inside the while loop. Also check the code
>   Comments for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Well the big issue is that you never change the value of userInput after the very first check. So regardless of whether they type "Yes" or "No" at the end of the loop, it will keep looping. You never even give the user the option to input anything at the end of the loop when you ask if they want to enter another patient. Secondly you should probably be checking if they entered "yes, Yes, YES, y" using a to lower function